# Why is my app able to run on newer devices, but not older devices(backwards compatibility build.gradle issue)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an android application where I'm using a `JsonObjectRequest` and Android's Volley.

My app seems to runs perfectly fine on Android's Pixel XL API 30(printing out the desired output), but doesn't work with Android's Pixel 2 API 29, even though I've defined `minSdkVersion 16` in `build.gradle`

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.krish.parsedata"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
}
```

This is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue queue;
    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    String apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    String getApiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getApiUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("url", "onCreate: " + response.getString("title"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("url2", "There was an error");
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);



    }

}
```

Thank you!

Update: This keeps on showing up:

```
Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.krish.parsedata">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ParseData">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE: It works on all API 30 level devices, but not on anything lower, I've tryed changing min sdk version, complie sdk version, and build sdk version, no luck. Not sure what to do. Help would be appreciated a lot. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Doesn't print out log message in `MainActivity.java`. Essentially, not functional with lower API devices.

Comment: Care to add the relevant code? Without it, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Show the log error as well

Comment: Did you debug this on the described device and see what happens?

Comment: Yes I get error INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK, I've tried changing target_sdk, and min_sdk, still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am getting a new error now. Will put it in my post. Thanks.

Comment: What `Android Studio` version do you use? Please show `Manifest`

Comment: 4.1.3, I added Manifest file. Thanks.

Comment: It doens't like junit.4.+ in build.gradle, and tells me I have invalid JDK settings: Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
    Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
    spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
    while using Android Studio.

Comment: When I change it to the JAVA_HOME JDK settings, error still occurs.

Comment: @tomerpacific I've tried using the debugger, although it doesn't help since it just shows the object request going to the queue and then doesn't provide any information from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the error. The problem had nothing to do with my code or build configuration, it was the emulator itself. I deleted/re-installed the emulator, and things are working normal.

Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same problem.